# what is OpenNMS in http header

Tags: http

After receiving http packets from a website I see a request packet which its http header is like this,what does it mean "OpenNMS HttpMonitor\r\n" ?Its source address is not from that web page which I open!

GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Connection: CLOSE \r\n
    User-Agent: OpenNMS HttpMonitor\r\n
    \r\n

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may well be Rackspace's monitoring solution for cloud servers. Might be wrong though. Might be worth contacting your hosting provider to see if it's them. You can sort of check this by seeing if your server IP is in the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Um, not sure why it is appearing in your context, but OpenNMS is a network monitoring suite that we used to use at work to monitor our network nodes.

http://www.opennms.org/

Your IP may be erroneously being monitored by some corporation? ^^